# How can I join every two items in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to join every two characters in an array of names but not sure how to implement this in javascript:

Here is my array:

```
[
  'Jerry',   'Underwood', 'Bob',
  'Sheldon', 'Jason',     'Mendoza',
  'Alex',    'Jackson',   'Peter',
  'Makah',   'Suzie',     'Alisson',
  'John',    'Winger',    'Pete',
  'McFall',  'Alexis',    'Caper',
  'Mason',   'Jacobson',  'Manager1',
  'Manager', 'Employee',  'Emp'
]
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
[
  'Jerry Underwood', 'Bob Sheldon', 'Jason Mendoza', 
  'Alex Jackson', etc
]
```

I have tried looping through it but I am unsure of how to only join every two items in the array. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this with JS?

Comment: A loop that increments the `i` by `+2` each time could be a starting point

Comment: Show us what you have tried though.  You said you tried something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), 
take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, 
post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
const arr = [......];
const final = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  if (!arr[i+1])
    break;
  final.push(`${arr[i]} ${arr[i+1]}`);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: That worked great, thank you! Did not realized I could concatenate it like that.